# How to replicate this animated drop down menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to replicate the animated drop down menu here but I am having trouble.

Here is the code I am trying out, but it is not working as expected:
http://jsfiddle.net/EHw6n/

The menus are stacking on top of each other and I think I created an unnecessary mess. Can anyone help me fix this or maybe there is something out there that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing some styles. The menu items required a value for the left property so they weren't stacked. Also; The drops downs needs the background position setting to move the image sprite.

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EHw6n/1/